# Remove empty vertex groups?

Tags: vertex-groups

Is there an easy (non scripted or standard script) way to remove all empty vertex groups (weight is zero).

Is there an easy way to remove all empty vertex groups vertex groups regardless of current weight assignments?

Comment: Do you mean remove the vertex from the vertex groups? or remove the vertex groups which are not used by any vertices?

Comment: @ideasman42 - remove the vertex groups.